# The value of $230-220\times 0.5$ is $120$, but the teacher says $5!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$230-220\times 0.5$$ Of course the answer is $120$, but the teacher says the answer is $5!\,$. What!!?

Here we apply the law of BIDMAS, then
$$220\times 0.5=110$$
$$230-110=120$$

> How on earth did my teacher got $5!$

Comment: The exclamation mark is the notation used for factorials, it means to multiply the number by all the positive integers less than it, say 5!=5*4*3*2*1 or in general n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1

Comment: On many calculators, if you punch in 230 - 220 x 0.5, you will get $(230-220)\times0.5=5$.

Answer (score 2):

Neither your teacher is wrong nor is you and your friend. Actually $5!$ doesn't means what you are understanding. Indeed, $5!$ (read as $5$ factorial) is nothing but the product of the first $5$ natural numbers. To be more precise, $$n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n$$Thus, in your case $5!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5=120$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $5!=5\times4\times3\times2\times1=120$. It's a joke!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $5!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5=120$

Answer (score 0):

Lol i dont know if you have learned about this, but $5!$ = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120 . If you had learn this then he/she got you